# Paste commands into terminal and have them run one after the other even if one takes a password

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

If I try to run multiple commands, and let's say there is one SSH that I must perform that requires a password, once I type said password, the rest of the commands do not execute.

Before you tell me to setup an SSH key, ironically, the process is TO setup an SSH key just by pasting in the commands.

If I lost you somewhere, let me know and I will re-word it. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide some code, please? I don't see at which point your script stops.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/594793/how-to-paste-multiple-bash-commands-into-a-shell-without-losing-some

Answer (score 1):

You can execute multiple commands serially by separating them with the `&&` operator. It will continue executing the next command if the previous command(s) were executed successfully.

Example:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo && /bin/true
```

Example of the second command not executing due to the first command:

```
/bin/false && cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

(This is assuming you're using the bash shell)

If you don't care if the command executed successfully, you can separate them with a semicolon `;`.

Comment: This does not seem to work when the command requires a yes or no.

Comment: I did this in a bash terminal session. It ran all of the commands first, and printed out output afterwards. So first 4 commands ran, then 4 outputs. I would have expected the output of each command to follow the command that generated it.